# Android Search Activity

Tags: android

I have created a `CardView` (Using `Fragment`) which loads data from server. Also added a `SearchView` in the `Toolbar`. Now I am adding a search `Activity`. However while adding search `Activity` I feel like I have to copy all the methods and layout elements from the main `Activity`. I don't feel it will be a right solution.

Comment: Sounds like you either should have a common base class for both activities, or that you didn't sufficiently abstract out your UI components for reuse.

Comment: why don't you keep your common layouts in a seperate xml and use <include> tag.

Comment: Yes, I can. I don't have problem with that. Can you suggest something about activity methods as well. Although I am using a common view interface for both activities. I just wanted to make sure this is the right approach. Or you can share any example. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask